# C stdio fgets()

Tags: c, fgets, stdio

In class, I encountered this code snippet

```
for (numlines = 0, (fp=fopen("thefile",'r')); feof(fp); numlines++ ) { 
    fgets(fp, buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp);
    ...
}
```

In the for-loop header, two things, namely `numlines` and `fp`, can be initialized, right?

Then in the body of the for loop,

```
fgets(fp, buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp);
```

this is what confuses me.. I thought the `fgets()` function takes these parameters

```
char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)
```

Any idea what the 2 fps are doing?

Comment: An error? That shouldn't even compile. Unless the code redefines `fgets` or does some other trickery (which would be bad).

Comment: That code snippet is pure garbage, period.

Comment: Where did you encounter it? Maybe finding the problems was the goal of the exercise. `feof(fp)` is also wrong.

Comment: @namesake22  You can find a code of any bad quality. But why should it be discussed?:)

Comment: `fopen("thefile",'r')` should *definitely* cause a compiler warning.

Comment: Also `feof(fp)` as loop condition is wrong (the opposite would be correct). I guess the actual task was to find and fix the errors?

Answer (score 2):

> Any idea what the 2 fps are doing?

It's a typo - the author clearly got their wires crossed when writing that statement.  The compiler should complain about that call.

It should also complain about `fp=fopen("thefile",'r')` - the second argument should be `"r"`, not `'r'`.

I count *at least* 3 additional problems in those two lines of code:

- The author does not verify that the `fopen` call succeeded before reading from the file;
- *NEVER* use `feof` as a loop condition - it won't return true until *after* you try to read past the end of the file, meaning you'll loop once too often, and it won't catch an actual read error;
- Following on from the previous, you should check the result of `fgets` to make sure it succeeded.

IMO, that code *should* be written as

```
fp = fopen( "thefile", "r" );
if ( !fp )
{
  // unable to open file, bail out here
}

for ( numlines = 0; fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, fp ); numlines++ )
{
  // do stuff with buffer
}

if ( feof( fp ) )
{
  // normal end of file
}
else
{
  // error on read, handle as appropriate
}
```

While you *can* call `fopen` as part of the initializer expression in the `for` loop, you should do that as a separate operation and make sure it was successful *before* getting into the loop.

Check the result of `fgets` as your loop condition.  If it returns `NULL`, *then* check to see if the reason was EOF or a read error.